# javascript/jquery - entire block of script (between script tags) is disabled without error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a bad statement, the entire block of script is disabled. Other blocks of script are not disabled. I don't get a script error.  I've spent  hours fumbling around with this code.  It's on a Coldfusion 9 server and I use Eclipse to edit and format. If I comment out the line ->alert($(e.target).is(":checked")); the code works.  I'm wondering why I don't get me javascript errors anymore.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('.StartOver').live('click', function () {
        var ReInitAnswer = confirm('Are you sure you want TO DELETE ALL temp dupe records AND start over FROM SCRATCH? \nIt may take a couple OF hours.');
        if (ReInitAnswer) {
          // submit the form TO BEGIN re-creating the temp table
          document.forms["dupeIndivs"].submit();
          //return true; 
        } else {
          alert('canceled');
          return false;
        }
      });

      $('.notdupe').live('click', function (e) {
        alert("indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"));
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe",
          data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"),
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // show error alert(errorThrown); 
          }
        });
        alert($(e.target).is(":checked"));
        if $(e.target).is(":checked" == 'True') {
            $firstTD = $(this).parent().siblings().first()
            alert($firstTD.text());
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=CheckDupeGroup",
                data: "dupegrouptocheck" + $firstTD.text(),
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show error alert(errorThrown); 
                },
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert(response);
                }   
            });
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've never seen such writing : `if $(e.target).is(":checked" == 'True') {`. Is it working ? It's particularly awful.

Comment: You ain't seen nothing yet. This is what happens when you expect your IDE to give you a little help and it doesn't.  Bad habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should:

```
if $(e.target).is(":checked" == 'True') {
```

be:

```
if ( $(e.target).is(":checked") ) {
```

Comment: That's what happens when you get frustrated.  You miss the simple things.  Good catch. I'm still wondering where the javascript errors went.